# How would I make the points appear on a windows forms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to build a basic winforms application that draws a triangle from points I have specified, I cannot get the program to display the lines on the form whatsoever when the button is clicked. I am not very sure what code to put in the button. I am very new to c# and have some of the basics down but need a little extra help. Thank you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DrawPolygonPontF(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create pen.
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        // Create points.
        PointF point1 = new PointF(50.0F, 50.0F);
        PointF point2 = new PointF(100.0F, 25.0F);
        PointF point3 = new PointF(200.0F, 5.0F);

        PointF[] curvePoints =
        {
             point1,
             point2,
             point3,
        };

        // Draw.
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Paint` event  `private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {  DrawPolygonPontF(e); }`

Comment: Where abouts shall I add the DrawPolygonPontF(e); in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `Paint` event (click `Paint` event in `Form1` properties and put `DrawPolygonPontF(e);`)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    ...
    private bool m_ShowTriangle = false;

    // private: drawing triangle is an implementation detail; let's not expose it
    private void DrawPolygonPontF(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create pen. (do not forget to release it - "using")
        using (Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3)) 
        {
            // Create points.
            PointF point1 = new PointF(50.0F, 50.0F);
            PointF point2 = new PointF(100.0F, 25.0F);
            PointF point3 = new PointF(200.0F, 5.0F);

            PointF[] curvePoints =
            {
                 point1,
                 point2,
                 point3,
            };

            // Draw.
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
        }
    }

    // Whenever system wants to paint the form...
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
    {
        // ...draw the triangle (if we want it)
        if (m_ShowTriangle)
            DrawPolygonPontF(e);
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_ShowTriangle = true;
        // All the area of the window is invalid (i.e. wants repainting)
        Invalidate();
        // And the area should be re-painted at once 
        Update();  
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do this with the button, so when it is clicked the triangle appears?

Comment: @BLAKE ELLIS: you can introduce `m_ShowTriangle` flag then (if we should draw the rectangle). Set the flag to `true` and do not forget to cast a magic spell `Invalidate(); Update();` for system to redraw the window.

Comment: No need to `Update()` after `Invalidate()`. You'll actually draw the shapes twice.

Comment: @Jimi: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Invalidate "Remarks: Calling the `Invalidate` method *does not force a synchronous paint*; to force a synchronous paint, call the `Update` method after calling the `Invalidate` method. When this method is called with no parameters, the entire client area is added to the update region."

Comment: Yes, you don't want to force a synchronous paint. You just need to *insert* the request in the message queue. It will be fullfilled immediately. The underlying caching/buffering is smart enough to repaint what's necessary. It will be more visible if you have a lot of shapes to paint.

Comment: Hi again Dmitry, do you know what would be the best way to change this program so that a tick event added +1 onto all coordinates and then redraws the triangle?